# angular can access Zone from vscode intelligence ,but return undefined when run in chrome

Tags: angular, typescript, zone

When I try to use Zone in **ngOnInit** on my angular application, so I set an breakpoint on line 11th, and I get the function Zone(parent,zoneSpec){....}, but return undefined when start in chrome? 
this is my code:(https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c98byw)

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  ngOnInit(): void {
            // RootZone is ambient and it is 
            indistinguishable from no Zone.
            console.dir(Zone)
            let rootZone = Zone.current;
            // We create a new zone by forking an 
                                 existing zone.
            let zoneA = rootZone.fork({name: 'zoneA'});

            // Each zone has a name for debugging
            console.log(rootZone.name);
            // (rootZone.name).toEqual('<root>');
            // expect(zoneA.name).toEqual('zoneA');
            // // Child zone knows about its parent zone. 
                          (one way reference)
            // expect(zoneA.parent).toBe(rootZone);
  }
  title = 'app';
  @ViewChild('vc', {read: ViewContainerRef}) vc: ViewContainerRef;

constructor(private zone:NgZone,
  private _compiler: Compiler,
            private _injector: Injector,
            private _m: NgModuleRef<any>) {
}
```

When debugging in vscode:
 I can Access from the vscode intellgence.
But error was threw from chrome:

```
AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of undefined
    at AppComponent.push../src/app/app.component.ts.AppComponent.ngOnInit (app.component.ts:12)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:9035)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10299)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10261)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:10894)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:10854)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:10846)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10243)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11136)
View_AppComponent_Host_0 @ AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1
proxyClass @ compiler.js:10048
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugContext_.logError @ core.js:11098
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1679
(anonymous) @ core.js:4524
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:3719
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick @ core.js:4524
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef._loadComponent @ core.js:4551
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.bootstrap @ core.js:4493
(anonymous) @ core.js:4294
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef._moduleDoBootstrap @ core.js:4294
(anonymous) @ core.js:4260
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
onInvoke @ core.js:3760
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:387
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
(anonymous) @ zone.js:872
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
onInvokeTask @ core.js:3751
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:420
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:578
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:252
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:862
ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:962
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:4289
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:43
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:30
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 0, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
View_AppComponent_Host_0 @ AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1
proxyClass @ compiler.js:10048
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugContext_.logError @ core.js:11098
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1684
(anonymous) @ core.js:4524
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:3719
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick @ core.js:4524
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef._loadComponent @ core.js:4551
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.bootstrap @ core.js:4493
(anonymous) @ core.js:4294
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef._moduleDoBootstrap @ core.js:4294
(anonymous) @ core.js:4260
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
onInvoke @ core.js:3760
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:387
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
(anonymous) @ zone.js:872
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
onInvokeTask @ core.js:3751
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:420
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:578
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:252
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:862
ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:962
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:4289
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:43
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:30
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
core.js:3077 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to specify that it's on the window object.

If you use `console.dir(window["Zone"])` instead, you will see that the function is logged to the console as expected

Alternately, you can add `let Zone = window["Zone"]` to the first line of `ngOnInit`

Comment: it's work,  thank you so much, but I still wonder why  the vscode can intelligent that, it means the vscode intelligence was not sync with real environment?

Comment: I believe that vscode does not have access to the run-time. If this has solved the issue, do you mind marking it as accepted by clicking the tick? That way if anyone has the same issue they can find this easier